# Heroku webpack deploy port binding error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, npm, webpack

I have package.json with all the dependencies and start script with webpack. On deploying to heroku i am getting Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

```
"scripts": {
"start": "webpack-dev-server --test"
},
```

Webpack config file.

```
var config = {
 entry: './main.js',

output: {
  path:'./',
  filename: 'index.js',
},

devServer: {
  inline: true,
  port: process.env.PORT || 8010
},

module: {
  loaders: [
     {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',

        query: {
           presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
     },
     { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
  ]
}
}
```

module.exports = config;

Comment: why you want the port if you are hosting it on heroku ??

Comment: @MayankShukla  that is just for running on localhost. I tried to remove that port also but still not working

Comment: @RahulTailwal: were you able to solve this ? kindly share

Answer (score 1):

Kinda a late tho...
The above code wont work on heroku because the webpack devServer is for development.
For production you need to create a separate webpack.prod.config.js and pass the `const port = (process.env.PORT || 8010)` using express ..
Here is [Boiler Plate react app](https://github.com/BabuBahir/react-node-example) for making webpack configs which are heroku ready 
.

Comment: This worked for me, webpack-dev-server should just be a devDependency. A separate server file with a variable port, got me up and running on Heroku